# Non-smoothness of equivalence relation on Möbius band

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, foliations

Consider the open Möbius band $M$. This has a well-known foliation by circles, letting the central circle 'go around once' and all other circles go around twice.

Suppose we wish to consider the equivalence relation
$$ \mathcal{R} = \{(x,y) \rvert \text{x and y lie on the same leaf} \} \subset M\times M.$$

It is known that this is not a smooth manifold. My problem is I can't really grasp what this object looks like. Apparently, it is the union of two $3$-manifolds, with a singular intersection (the two-manifold given by $L \times L$, with $L$ the central circle. (Which is why this can't be a smooth manifold.)

Does anyone have any tips on 'visualising' (or even just begin tackling) what this object looks like?

EDIT:I might have a clue where the two 3−manifolds come from. The foliation is due to the circle going around the manifold twice. I'm thinking that perhaps, we look at the restrictions x y if x and y lie on the same circle (going around once), and the restriction x y if x and y lie on the circle going the opposite direction. These will give two 3−manifolds (if they are even manifolds) whose singular intersection is L×L. –

Comment: Why do you say it's the union of two 3-manifolds? It looks to me like, if you remove the central circle piece, you just get a product of an open annulus and a circle.

Comment: Hi, let me think about what you just said! In the meanwhile, I got that information from THE HOLONOMIC IMPERATIVE AND THE HOMOTOPY
GROUPOID OF A FOLIATED MANIFOLD  by John Philips

Comment: Sorry, English is not my first language. What is an open annulus exactly? Is it a regular annulus but where the central 'circle' and the outer 'circle' are removed?

Comment: Yes, it is an an open interval times a circle.

Comment: Right, I got the same as you did. So we get a filled torus without boundary. I would then assume we can get the full space by adding the central leaf to the picture?

Comment: Yes, but this is not a filled torus (which is a product of a disk and a circle). I think as a set, you're getting the disjoint union of $(0,1)\times S^1\times S^1$ from the non-central circles, and $S^1\times S^1$ from the central circle. The topology is a little more subtle though.

Comment: Yes, I figured I messed up earlier. I'm trying to get the topology to work, but it is quite messy.